# forloop count for a nestedlist

Tags: python, nested, counter

Hey all I'm struggling figure out to count in python i need to it count names then it has to adds them to a dictionary or if there's is another alternative way , so from the list it needs to match  the name in the second list

```
list_1 = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
nested_list_1= [['red','hair','peaches'],['green', 'hair', 'roses'],['green', 'same', 'roses'],['red', 'same', 'roses'],['green', 'same', 'roses']]
dic = {}
count = 0
for x in list_1:

    # print(x)
    # count = 
    for y in nested_list_1:
   
        if x in y[0]:
           
            count +=1
            dic[y[0]] = count
```

I have tried adding counter loop it count the name but only for the first it then counts the second name in the list but it doesn't count correctly after that

I need to iterate and count the name and alos need to count if that list has hair or not. Basically i need to count that and add it to the dic and make it like nested dic so for example, with the pseudo code red [ appeared; 2 hair ; 1] green [ appeared; 3 hair ; 0

Comment: What is the expected result for this input?

Comment: Are you trying to count how many sublists start with each color in `list_1`? `x` is a sublist, so `x[0]` is the value you want to look for in `list_1`; you don't need to iterate over `x` at all. Something like `dic = collections.Counter(color for color, * in nest_list_1 if color in list_1)` may suffice. (See the documentation for the `collections` module for more information.)

Comment: I need to iterate and count the name and alos need to count if that list has hair or not.    Basically i need to count that and add it to the dic and make it like  nested dic so for example, with the pseudo code red [ appeared; 2 hair ; 1] green [ appeared; 3 hair ; 0]

Comment: That output is not valid Python. Please update your question with the desired output in Python syntax. It mentions "appeared", but there is nothing in your code that does anything with "appeared". Please show your attempt to get that in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with just one counter. I suppose that for each distinct word you'll want a separate count, so use the entry in `dic` to see what the previous count was, and add one to it.

Secondly, for the key in your dictionary you don't want to use `y[0]`, but `x`, as *that* is the word you're counting:

```py
for x in list_1:
    for y in nested_list_1:
        if x in y[0]:
            if x not in dic:
                dic[x] = 1
            else:
                dic[x] +=1
```

If you want also an entry in the result for the strings that were not found (so with a count of 0), then first create your dictionary, and iterate the nested list only once:

```py
dic = { key: 0  for key in list_1 }
for y in nested_list_1:
    for x in y:
        if x in dic:
            dic[x] +=1
```

Comment: I need to iterate and count the name and alos need to count if that list has hair or not. Basically i need to count that and add it to the dic and make it like nested dic so for example, with the pseudo code red [ appeared; 2 hair ; 1] green [ appeared; 3 hair ; 0

Comment: Can you please provide the exact data structure you want as output in valid Python syntax? I don't understand this output that you gave.

Comment: so the exact output is for example if printed out  would look like this. {'red': {entrys': 2, 'hair': 1}, 'green': {'tak': 3, 'hair': 1}}

Comment: You updated your comment. So you want a *nested* dict? But your code only creates one dict, not a nested dict, so it seems you are aiming for something that you haven't tried yet. What is the trouble you have when you try to create a nested dict? Also where does "entrys" come from? Why your second nested dict does not have "entrys", but "tak"? There is nothing in your code that does something with "entrys" or "tak". Seems you are stretching the question to something else.

Comment: do i have the right idea or am completely off